# How can I check an address to see what custom tokens has been generated at it?

Tags: accounts, tokens, balances

How can I check an address to see what custom tokens has been generated at it?

This is a testnet (Ropsten) address for example:

0xc8f836f4236e3e58f5417589b2d677abd7558cd5

I know that on Ropsten it has a custom token.

I am using Geth and I want to know what I should input to get a list of the tokens created at the address above and the name of the token.

Vesa

Comment: By created, do you mean "token contract deployed"?

Comment: your question is not clear, please provide more information.

Comment: Clarification: I created a custom token using tokenfactory. The service used this address for the creation of the tokens: 0xc8f836f4236e3e58f5417589b2d677abd7558cd5. I know the name of the token already BUT I want to be able to use Geth to check the quantity and name of the tokens that are associated with that address. If it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Etherescan has a testnet scraper. You should be able to get the data you want from there (https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xc8f836f4236e3e58f5417589b2d677abd7558cd5).

Using the 'geth' command line to get the information, would involve a whole series of eth.getBlockByNumber calls followed by eth_getTransactionByHash (or some other combination), followed by a bunch of processing to figure out which transactions were against your address, and which succeeded to create tokens.

There is a feature is called RPC (described here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) that can help as well. It's similar to the options available on the command line.

I don't know if parity has a console. I haven't been able to find it, if it does.

Comment: Parity does not have a console as far as I know. I would prefer to use Geth if possible yes.